# Platform Developer I & Force.com IDE

Tags: ide, certification

I'm attending Destination Success on the Platform Developer I track and the pre-work focuses on the Force.com IDE/Eclipse. Though new to development, I'm using MavensMate/Sublime Text. Does the certification exam require specific knowledge of the IDE/Eclipse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Platform Developer 1 does not require you to Code during exam (Although it expects you that you have good understanding of how to write apex ,visualforce and work with lightning components)or does not expect you to know an IDE like eclipse in depth.There are plenty of IDE's available today and you can choose one depending on your preference .

One thing you may want to get familiarize is tooling and metadata API's as all these IDE's use these API's.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to coding, and on a fast learning track. Appreciate the additional tip!